# How to use Nextjs API route instead if axios

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, axios, blockchain

I was following a tutorial where he used axios to fetch the data. But now the axios endpoints are not working (giving a server error)

So, was wondering how to use Nextjs api routes in my project instead of axios.

Would be really helpful, if you could guide me through that

`Landing.tsx page`

```js
    const fetchData = async () => {
        const response = await axios(
          "https://liwaiw1kuj.execute-api.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com"
        ).get("/tasks");
        const tempData = get(response, "data.data", []);
        setData(tempData);
        setLoading(false);
      };
    
      useEffect(() => {
        fetchData();
      }, []);
```

code of one of the component page ->

```js
const ipfs = await axios(
          "https://liwaiw1kuj.execute-api.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com"
        ).post(
          "/ipfs",
          {
            ...description,
            salary,
            discord,
            whatsapp,
            telegram,
            signal,
          }
        );
```

Or if there is any other method to do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To replace Axios with Next.js API routes follow below steps:

1. **Create Routes:** In the `api` folder, make separate route files (e.g., `tasks.js` and `ipfs.js`).
2. **Move Logic:** Migrate Axios logic to these API routes. Use `req` and `res` for handling requests and responses.
3. **Update Components:** Replace Axios calls with `fetch` for API routes.

Example for `Landing.tsx`:

```
const fetchData = async () => {
  try {
    const response = await fetch("/api/tasks");
    const tempData = await response.json();
    setData(tempData);
    setLoading(false);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
};
```

Example for component page:

```
const ipfsResponse = await fetch("/api/ipfs", {
  method: "POST",
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({
    ...description,
    salary,
    discord,
    whatsapp,
    telegram,
    signal,
  }),
});
```

By using Next.js API routes, server-side handling is streamlined within your Next.js project.